# Does [Ma'achalot Assurot 17:22] establish any type of cooking Oil is kosher?

Tags: gentiles, kashering-kosherization, oil

We read in [Ma'achalot Assurot 17:22](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968273/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-17.htm) that :

> The oil of gentiles is permitted. One who forbids it commits a great sin, for he rebels against [the teachings] of the [High] Court who permitted it. Even if the oil was cooked, it is permitted. It is not forbidden because of gentile cooking, because we partake of oil uncooked. Nor is it forbidden, because of prohibited foods, because meat impairs [the flavor of] oil and spoils it.
>
> שֶׁמֶן שֶׁל עַכּוּ''ם מֻתָּר. וּמִי שֶׁאוֹסְרוֹ הֲרֵי זֶה עוֹמֵד בְּחֵטְא גָּדוֹל. מִפְּנֵי שֶׁמַּמְרֶה עַל פִּי בֵּית דִּין שֶׁהִתִּירוּהוּ. וַאֲפִלּוּ נִתְבַּשֵּׁל הַשֶּׁמֶן הֲרֵי זֶה מֻתָּר. וְאֵינוֹ נֶאֱסָר לֹא מִפְּנֵי בִּשּׁוּלֵי עַכּוּ''ם מִפְּנֵי שֶׁנֶּאֱכָל כְּמוֹת שֶׁהוּא חַי. וְלֹא מִפְּנֵי גִּעוּלֵי עַכּוּ''ם מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהַבָּשָׂר פּוֹגֵם אֶת הַשֶּׁמֶן וּמַסְרִיחוֹ

[Question] **Does Ma'achalot Assurot 17:22 establish any type of cooking Oil is kosher?**

Comment: Kosher and the issue of gentile oil is not connected at all. To be kosher it needs to follow the kosher dietary laws, not to be from forbidden fats etc.,  the gentile oil is permitted ONLY if it's otherwise kosher unlike wine, milk bread etc. That are not permitted even if they're kosher

Comment: @Chatzkel That's true, but maybe you can give an example of how cooking oil on the shelf at the store could possibly be not otherwise kosher, given this Rambam? Let's say then any bottle of oil in the store that is labeled with the name of a vegetable. Corn. Peanut. Canola.

Comment: Vegetable oil is kosher as long as there's no other ingredient. However there's oils that have lard and other ingredients that are not kosher. I've never actually looked and checked but the ou seems to say it exists.

Comment: @Chatzkel So there's no need for a hashgacha on a plain bottle of corn oil that just lists "corn" as the ingredient since it can't possibly be treif?

Comment: @double AA theoretically yes. However (I am in the food production business so I know a little about this) the processing can involve possible issues (refinery, processing lines) as well as mislabeling scenarios. However, in a case like you mentioned it would be ok except the issue with cleaning the lines which is a very tedious process

Comment: @Chatzkel And why do the lines need to be cleaned according to this rambam???????????????????

Comment: @DoubleAA Because it could have had a product using lard (as an example).

Comment: @sabbahillel That wouldn't be a problem... Did you see the source in the question that we're discussing?

Comment: @DoubleAA I looked at the source. It is a matter of bishul akum not treifus. The processing of cooking oil in our day is different from that of the time of the Rambam and can therefore become treif. Also we can no longer rely on what they have done to prepare it without a hasgacha

Comment: @sabbahillel He literally says you can use the same equipment even though it may have been used for lard, the exact opposite of what you said. What is different about our day than back then that is relevant?

Comment: See the footnotes 63 and 64. The methodology of thos times was different than what is done nowadays. As a result, we can no longer rely on what he could have relied on then. As an example, see footnote 3.

Comment: @sabba No, this halacha is not relying on someone to taste it. If we did that then for sure it would be kosher since no one can taste minute amounts of lard residue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that what the Rambam is really telling us here is that

- **there is no concern of *bishul akum* with oil** (i.e., food cooked by non-Jews which is normally forbidden) because oil can be consumed raw (e.g., together with bread) and such products are exempted from the interdiction of *bishul akum*
- **oil that was cooked by non-Jews in their dishes is not forbidden due to the taste absorbed from the utensils**, because that taste would be detrimental (the assumption being that the utensil wasn't used in the last 24 hours)

The Rambam bases his statement on the gemara in [Avoda Zara 38b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.38b.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), see there with commentaries.

What the Rambam is **NOT** telling us here is that any type of cooking oil is kosher per se. Oil from animal fat wouldn't be, or oil from vegetable sources with forbidden additions.

For a very good synopsis on halacha in relation to modern oil production methods see [here](https://www.ka.org.au/understanding-kosher/halachic-policy-guidelines/status-of-oils), and for more on what can happen in extreme cases with vegetable oil see [here](http://rabbikaganoff.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/olive-oil.pdf) and [here](https://archive.is/ocUJP).

Comment: Are you saying that vegetable oil produced on equipment that wasn't kashered is fine according to this rambam?

Comment: In your "extreme cases" I see no evidence that the oil ever became not kosher according to this rambam. What are you pointing out? Mixing olive with soy? Who cares? Processing on non-kashered equipment? Who cares?

Comment: @DoubleAA to your first question, no, if you know unkosher products were used on a production line, even the Rambam wouldn't agree that oil manifactured there is kosher. The gemara bases its reasoning on a *sfeik sfeika* - if you have facts that the production line is not kosher, or might not be kosher, it is a different story

Comment: THAT is something that, if accurate, actually would answer the question!

Comment: @mbloch - Exactly. The issue of "oil from vegetable sources [with forbidden additions]" is very confusing in regards to the 'great sin' of Ma'achalot Assurot 17:22. | So do we even need to check grocery store labels of cooking oils?

Comment: @DoubleAA to your second question, diluting oil with forbidden animal fat would make it non kosher but that is not what the Rambam discusses here. On a separate note, I agree that "unkosher" vegetable oil seems hard to find in the real world but I have learned that industrial food manufacturing can sometimes reserve surprises (e.g., I learned that the same steam pipes are sometimes used to heat "pork and beans" in one vat, then plain steamed vegetables in a second, making these seemingly kosher vegetables non-kosher)

Comment: It may make the vegetables non-kosher (debatable) but why would it make oil not kosher according to this rambam?

Comment: @חִידָה that is a question for your Rav in the country you live in ... I know in Switzerland and France virgin olive oil were permitted without checking. But sometimes they had grape seed oil which can be problematic

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't write that it makes oil not kosher according to this Rambam. I wrote the Rambam did not address the composition of the oil. Probably because in his time all they knew was pure olive oil without additives. Food manufacturing was likely much simpler

Comment: @mbloch Oil is still sold without additives. Vegetable oil is just vegetable oil.

Comment: @Double AA I spoke with an RC who deals with oils and he says the main problem is residue of lard and other treif ingredients on the line that get mixed in with the heat when they process the vegetable oil. Why would the Rambam permit that?

Comment: @Chatzkel Seemingly because וְלֹא מִפְּנֵי גִּעוּלֵי עַכּוּ''ם מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהַבָּשָׂר פּוֹגֵם אֶת הַשֶּׁמֶן וּמַסְרִיחוֹ You think not perfectly cleaned dishes is a new problem? Clearly he thought any residues are natlap and/or batel. This is getting ridiculous.

Comment: Why didn't rambam write "oil is only ok if you made sure they scrubbed their pots first" ???????????????????????? Anyone listening?

Comment: The Rambam is talking about Bsis Din Sharu Mishcha, not kosher or bliyos. Perhaps in his times it wasn't as common, or it was minuscule. Today it's different

Comment: @Chatzkel Lol I don't think anyone here expects anyone else to actually believe that kitchen hygiene standards were better 1000 years ago, but at least now you're finally trying to grapple with the source instead of pretending it doesn't exist. Rambam is explicitly talking about blios; I don't know what you mean there.

Comment: Rambam seems to  holds that סתם כלים של גוים בני יומן. See Kesef Mishneh to 17:18. Seems that Rambam is permitting cooked oil, even if we assume that the utensil was used in the last 24 hours.

Comment: @JoelK See too Lechem Mishneh 17:22

Comment: @double AA se Shulchan Aruch 114:7 Shach, Taz, etc. Its all talking about bliyos, not mamashus. On the processing lines, if it's not cleaned properly, there's mamashus. Maybe it's batul, maybe not. That's why you need a hechsher. 1000 years ago they knew how to clean as well, passuls even better than us as seen by the 7 samanim by kesem

Comment: @DoubleAA I feel like you’d appreciate this article: https://www.ka.org.au/understanding-kosher/halachic-policy-guidelines/status-of-oils

Comment: @Chatzkel Do you have a source for your claim that natlap doesn't apply the same to mamashus? (talking about cases where the mamashus is muat not meruba yd 103:2)

Comment: @Double AA Shukchan Aruch YD 122:3 https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.122?lang=bi  However I will concede that the Rambam himself argues and agrees with you. But since the Shulachan does not follow his opinion, the Hechsherim today are careful to properly clean it.

Comment: @JoelK yes that's the right answer, not this post.

Comment: @Chatzkel No no that's a different case. That's about if the residue itself is nifgam. Our case is where the residue is pogeim a particular food. We all can agree that the lard allegedly sitting on the equipment tastes good on its own or in a given food, but it doesn't taste good in oils (apparently).

Comment: @Double AA I hear, good point. However if they mix it into other oils it is hard to say it is Poigem

Comment: @Chatzkel Any mixing is incidental and doesn't indicate they prefer the taste of corn + lard residue over just corn. But anyway now you're talking metzius and I admit I have no idea what oils don't taste good when in what oils בפועל. Really it's very very very hard to imagine a kfeila would be able to taste any of these residues anyway lishvach or lifgam.